# Start Activity for result in Settings

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

When my app is started and location isn't enabled, the user is asked to turn it on. I've done it using `startActivity(intetnt)` and it works, but now I want it to be closed automatically after the user turns it on. I know it could be done using `StartActivityForResult`, but don't know how.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);                    
    startActivityForResult(intent,0x1002);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> but now I want it to be closed automatically after user turns on. I know it could be done using StartActivityForResult but dont know how

`startActivityForResult()` does exactly what name tells. It starts the activity and lets you get some results back from it. That's all.

You cannot close the activity you invoked unless it gives you such option (by i.e. expecting certain arguments passed in Bundle etc).

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0x1002:
            finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From your 1st Activity call the 2nd Activity using  startActivityForResult() method

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In 2nd Activity if you want to send data back:

```
 

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
```

If you don't want to return data:

```
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
    finish();
```

Now in your 1st Activity class write following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }//onActivityResult
```